# Ввод русских символов в C

Tags: c, кириллица

Учу чистый C по книге из серии Head First. Там был пример, что когда ты вводишь (на латинице) карту - тебе выводится ее ценность. Я решил переписать код и при вводе латинских символов все выводилось хорошо, но потом изменив код под проверку русских символов- код работал, но не корректно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(void)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
char card_name[3];
puts("Введите название карты: ");
scanf("%2s", card_name);
int val = 0;
if (card_name[0] == 'Т')
{
    val = 11;
} else if (card_name[0] == 'К')
{
    val = 10;
} else if (card_name[0] == 'Д')
{
    val = 10;
} else 
{
    val = atoi(card_name);
}
printf("Ценность вашей карты: %i\n", val);
return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Введите название карты: 
Д    
Ценность вашей карты: 0
```

Что делать? Или же C понимает только латиницу?

UPD: ос- Ubuntu 18.04, компилятор- gcc

Comment: Какая ОС, и что за компилятор?

Comment: ос- Ubuntu 18.04; компилятор- gcc;

Comment: Убунта небось кириллицу как Юникод вводит. Попробуйте wchar_t использовать. И да, напечатайте что именно оказывается в card_name после ввода символа.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 если вывести card_name с элементом массива программа крашится, если просто- то выводит все правильно, но при этом проверку все равно не проходит.  Пробовал делать так: card_name[0] == 'Д' и card_name[0] == "Д" и card_name == 'Д' и card_name == "Д", но никак не поддается(

Comment: Напечатайте просто три элемента массива card_name, приведенные к целому, чтобы поглядеть, какие коды туда попадают после ввода. Что-то вроде printf("\n\n 0=%i, 1=%i, 2=%i",(int)(card_name[0]),(int)(card_name[1]),(int)(card_name[2]));

Comment: И да, перед вводом не забудьте обнулить массив card_name, чтобы там мусор не болтался.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Вывелось: 0=-48, 1=-108, 2=0

Comment: Это когда букву "Д" вводите или букву "K"? И еще, напечатайте в hex коде. Строка принта будет выглядеть так: printf("\n\n 0=%x, 1=%x, 2=%x",(int)(card_name[0]),(int)(card_name[1]),(int)(card_name[2]));

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Введите название карты: Д 0=-48, 1=-108, 2=0 Хекс: 0=ffffffd0, 1=ffffff94, 2=0

Comment: А теперь введите букву "Е". И напишите какие hex коды пришли. По идее если есть ввод, то код должен отличаться на единицу от кода буквы "Д". Надеюсь, Вы не забыли обнулить массив card_name перед вводом? Еще у Вас ошибка в заголовке вопроса - написано "воод" вместо "ввод".

Comment: через utf-8 пробовали? (wchar_t, wprintf, wscanf)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 извините, не могли бы вы "пояснить" за "обнуление массива"? Просто как я писал в вопросе, что только учу Си и что такое обнуление массива я не знаю.

Comment: Перед вводом напишите: card_name[0]=0; card_name[1]=0; card_name[2]=0; Это и будет обнуление массива.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Введите название карты: 
Д
0=-48, 1=-108, 2=0
Хекс 0=ffffffd0, 1=ffffff94, 2=0 Введите название карты: 
Е
0=-48, 1=-107, 2=0
Хекс 0=ffffffd0, 1=ffffff95, 2=0

Comment: Ну вот, видите, у Вас от буквы "Д" приходит код 94, а от буквы "Е" приходит код 95. Значит ввод есть. Осталось понять, какая кодировка используется. Попробуйте, как посоветовал коллега acade, использовать wscanf. Похоже это действительно Юникод, но какой-то странный. Вообще-то, по моим понятиям, Юникод в Юниксе четырехбайтовый и кодовая страница кириллицы это 0x400. А тут какой-то 0xd0 лезет. А вообще-то если Вы только начинаете, то не заморачивайтесь с кодировками. Пока работайте в латинице, со временем разберетесь и с кириллицей. Главное что Убунта работает с кириллицей.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 уже сам смирился) Впринципе сейчас главное сам язык выучит, а не с кодировкой париться. Спасибо вам за то что потратили на меня свое время)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как кодировка utf-8, то русские буквы ( одна буква ) занимают два байта, а английские как всегда один байт. В этом случае можно использовать функцию проверки строки вот так.

```
if ( strncmp ( card_name, "Д", 2 ) == 0 ) {
  val = 10;
}
```

Но можно перед strncmp поставить символ восклицательный знак, что означает равенство на ноль и будет аналогично приведённому коду.

```
if ( !strncmp ( card_name, "Д", 2 ) ) {
  val = 10;
}
```

Comment: Расцеловал бы вас прямо сейчас!)) Спасибо вам огромное!